# How to get a full closed contour image

Tags: graphics, image-processing, computer-vision

In this program, I need to select the point on the contour image that has the same abscissa as the center of the contour and has the highest ordinate. However, since the contour is not full closed, the last line does not return any thing. How can I fix this problem.

[image]

```
edge = MorphologicalPerimeter[ColorNegate@img] // DeleteSmallComponents

coordinatescontour = PixelValuePositions[edge, 1] ;

center = Round[ComponentMeasurements[edge, "BoundingDiskCenter"][[1, 2]]];

radius = Round[ComponentMeasurements[edge, "BoundingDiskRadius"][[1, 2]]];

Show[edge,Graphics[{{Red, Circle[center, radius]}, {Green, Point[center]}}]]

        (*I need to select the point on the contour which has the same abscissa as the center point and has the highest ordinate *)

Sort[Select[coordinatescontour, #[[1]] == center[[1]]&]][[1]]
```

Comment: After the Show command, I see the contour, a green dot, and a red circle. Can you draw a picture of the point you want returned?

Comment: In `coordinatescontour  = [...] // DeleteSmallComponents` the `DeleteSmallComponents` is probably a mistake. Other than that, your code seems to do what you want already.

Comment: @nikie, Yes! it was the mistakes that caused  the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I changed your image processing code a bit, by removing the unnecessary `DeleteSmallComponents` and removing the white lines using `Closing`. I also added a line to detect the pixel above the center.

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQmQI.png"];   

edge = MorphologicalPerimeter[Closing[ColorNegate@img, DiskMatrix[1]]];
coordinatescontour = PixelValuePositions[edge, 1];
center = Round[ComponentMeasurements[edge, "BoundingDiskCenter"][[1, 2]]];
radius = Round[ComponentMeasurements[edge, "BoundingDiskRadius"][[1, 2]]];

top = SortBy[Select[coordinatescontour, #[[1]] == center[[1]] &], Last] // Last;

Show[
  edge, 
  Graphics[{{Red, Circle[center, radius]}, 
            {Green, Point[center]}, 
            {Blue, PointSize[0.03], Point[top]}
           }]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]